# How to gob encode struct with unexported pointer?

Tags: go

I have a struct that I can successfully gob encode and decode as follows:

```
type Node struct {
    Value int
    Next  *Node
}

myNode := Node{
    Value: 1,
    Next: &Node{
        Value: 2,
    },
}
var buf bytes.Buffer
enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
dec := gob.NewDecoder(&buf)
if err := enc.Encode(&myNode); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
var decodedNode Node
if err := dec.Decode(&decodedNode); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

I'd like to now hide the fields of `Node`:

```
type Node struct {
    value int
    next  *Node
}
```

Because the fields are no longer exported I have to now write custom `GobEncode` and `GobDecode` functions:

```
func (d *Node) GobEncode() ([]byte, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
    if err := encoder.Encode(d.value); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := encoder.Encode(d.next); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}

func (d *Node) GobDecode(b []byte) error {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(b)
    decoder := gob.NewDecoder(buf)
    if err := decoder.Decode(&d.value); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := decoder.Decode(&d.next); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

This doesn't work because of a nil value in `Node.next`:

```
panic: gob: cannot encode nil pointer of type *main.Node [recovered]
    panic: gob: cannot encode nil pointer of type *main.Node [recovered]
    panic: gob: cannot encode nil pointer of type *main.Node
```

I'm re-using `gob.NewEncoder` inside my custom function because I'm trying to re-use as much of the [encode package](https://golang.org/src/encoding/gob/encode.go) as possible.

Any suggestions for getting this working?

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#hdr-Basics), "Nil pointers are not permitted, as they have no value." You're writing your own encoding/decoding logic though, so you can encode it any way you choose.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid having to manually encode this as https://golang.org/src/encoding/gob/encode.go should do most of the work.

Comment: It will do most of the work, but it supports what it supports, and what it supports is clearly documented. You should only have to manually encode `nil`s.

Comment: Any suggestions for just encoding `nil`? I can check for `nil` then maybe encode it as a string `encoder.Encode("nil")`. However, when I call `decoder.Decode(...)` it expects a consistent type which won't work here.

Comment: I would ask yourself, why is it so important to make the Node fields un-exported in the first place? It seems to me like some obfuscation that requires extra work, maintenance, and possible bugs, for little payoff.